# How to combine a view based iPhone project with a C based command line tool project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view based iPhone project which performs some animations & suchlike, Seperately I have a C based command line tool project which I use to do some calculations.

I want to integrate the two, so that I can call my C based calculations function at a certain point in my original iPhone project.

The command line tool project is in the form of 2 files, calculations.pch & calculations.m.

I tried to add a new file to my original class & simply copy in the 2 new files (& importing calculations.pch in the View Controller) but upon building I get the error:

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Any suggestions? thanks in advance!

The .pch is quite sparse & looks like this:

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'Tester' target in the 'Tester' project.
//

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message the compiler gives (there is a little icon on the right you can click to expand the error messages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the .pch file from your project, as the same .pch is already compiled with an iPhone project by default. If that fails, you can always just copy-paste your functions into a new file in your iPhone project.